# In changing view from the original view of month to another view, why do I get Uncaught TypeError: n.cmdFormatter is not a function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, typeerror

I had this implementation working until I started adding jqueryui dialog boxes. The system works well until I click to change the view and do not see why?

Without all the PHP and other JS:

At base of body called [https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js">](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js%22%3E)

Then in script tags: (with other code as well - few 100's lines)

```
    const startdate = new Date();
    startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() - 90);
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        initialDate: start,
        initialView: view,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        businessHours: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
                dayHeaderFormat: {weekday: 'short' }
            },
            timeGridWeek: {
                titleFormat: 'D MMM',
                //dayHeaderFormat: {weekday: 'short'}
                dayHeaderFormat: 'ddd Do '
                //        titleFormat: { year: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
            },
            timeGridDay: {
                titleFormat: 'D MMM YY',
                dayHeaderFormat: 'ddd Do MMMM'
            },
            listMonth: {
                titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
                dayHeaderFormat: {weekday: 'long' }
            }
        },
        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'prev,next'
        },
        footerToolbar: {
            start: 'custom1 custom2 custom3',
            center: '',
            end: 'prev,next'
        },
        validRange: {
            start: startdate
        }
```

Comment: If the issue occurs when adding jqueryUI code, then please show an example including the code which causes the issue. We need a [mre] of the problem, not a working version which doesn't demonstrate the problem. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post when you're ready. Thanks.